# too-many-args for union of callables

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

If I run mypy on

```py
from typing import Callable

a: Callable[[str, str], str] | Callable[[str], str]

a('a', 'b')
```

then I get

```py
main.py:5: error: Too many arguments  [call-arg]
```

But, why?

How can I say that `a` can be a function which either takes two `str` arguments, or just one?

Comment: Is the second argument supposed to be optional with default, or is the function overloaded to accept 2 different signatures?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#annotating-callable-objects "Callable cannot express complex signatures such as functions that take a variadic number of arguments, overloaded functions, or functions that have keyword-only parameters. However, these signatures can be expressed by defining a `Protocol` class with a `__call__()` method:" - I guess Union of callables is also not able to represent that "variadic number of arguments", so you should look into Protocol

Comment: it can accept two signatures

Comment: As for the “why”, passing 2 arguments to a callable which can either take only 1 or take exactly 2 arguments is unsafe; If the callable happens to only take 1 argument, then the program will fail at runtime.

Comment: You define `a` to be either a callable that takes one argument or a callable with two arguments. It's ok for `a` to be `def a(x: str) -> str: return x`. Your `a('a', 'b')` will obviously fail with a `TypeError` in such case.